# @Autowired is not injecting my service in my managed bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to excute the following test:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = DBDataManipulatorServiceTestContext.class, loader =  
  SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
 @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
 public class UserInterfaceBeanTest {

 @Autowired
private DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService;
 .....

 @Test
public void testGetDistinctWorkPackageId() {

    WorkPackage workPackage1 = new WorkPackage();
    workPackage1.setWorkPackageId("TEST1");
    workPackage1.setWorkPackageName("WP_1");

    WorkPackage workPackage2 = new WorkPackage();
    workPackage2.setWorkPackageId("TEST2");
    workPackage2.setWorkPackageName("WP_2");

    WorkPackage workPackage3 = new WorkPackage();
    workPackage3.setWorkPackageId("TEST3");
    workPackage3.setWorkPackageName("WP_3");

    WorkPackage workPackage4 = new WorkPackage();
    workPackage4.setWorkPackageId("TEST4");
    workPackage4.setWorkPackageName("WP_4");

    Aircraft aircraft1 = new Aircraft();
    aircraft1.setAircraftId(50001);
    aircraft1.setModel("100");

    Aircraft aircraft2 = new Aircraft();
    aircraft2.setAircraftId(50002);
    aircraft2.setModel("100");

    aircraft1.addOrUpdateWorkPackageToAircraft(workPackage1);
    aircraft1.addOrUpdateWorkPackageToAircraft(workPackage3);

    aircraft2.addOrUpdateWorkPackageToAircraft(workPackage2);
    aircraft2.addOrUpdateWorkPackageToAircraft(workPackage3);

    Map<Integer, Aircraft> aircraftsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Aircraft>();
    aircraftsMap.put(50001, aircraft1);
    aircraftsMap.put(50002, aircraft2);


    UserInterfaceBean userInterfaceBean = new UserInterfaceBean();
    userInterfaceBean.setModel("100");

    aircraftsMap = dbDataManipulatorService.saveToDataBase(aircraftsMap);

    List<String> workPackgesIds = userInterfaceBean.getDistinctWorkPackageId();

    assertTrue(workPackgesIds.contains("TEST1"));
    assertTrue(workPackgesIds.contains("TEST2"));
    assertTrue(workPackgesIds.contains("TEST3"));
    assertTrue(!workPackgesIds.contains("TEST4"));
}
```

But I get ***NullPointerException***  due to ***dbDataManipulatorService*** that is not correctly injected, my serviceContext is the following:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DBDataManipulatorServiceContext {

.....

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setName("aircraft").setType(H2)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
    DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new  
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan("com");
    return lef;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = 
                                  new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}

.....
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem? and how to solve it.

**EDIT**

Here's my DBDataManipulatorServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DBDataManipulatorServiceImpl implements DBDataManipulatorService {

.....

}
```

And here's it's interface:

```
 public interface DBDataManipulatorService {


public AircraftRepository getAircraftRepository();

public Aircraft getAircraftById(String id);

public Map<Integer, Aircraft> saveToDataBase(Map<Integer, Aircraft> aircrafts);

public MyJob findJobByJobId(String jobId);

public WorkPackage findWorkPackageByAircraftIdAndWorkPackageId
                        (int aircraftId, String workPackageId);

public Aircraft findAircraftByaircraftId(int aircraftId);

public List<Aircraft> findAllAircrafts();

public List<String> findAllAvailableAircraftsModels();

public List<Aircraft> findAllAircraftsByModel(String model);

public List<WorkPackage> getWorkPackagesByAircraftModel(String model);
```

}

Comment: Question: Where is the configuration for your `DBDataManipulatorService` bean. It is not in your configuration right..

Answer (score 1):

You have a `@ComponentScan` but you have not put the name of the package to scan from. The default behavior is to scan from the package where you have put the `@ComponentScan` essentially the package of your `DBDataManipulatorServiceContext` config class. I am guessing this is not where your `DBDataManipulatorService` is, if so just specify a package name to your `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Please pay attention to my code. I already specified the package to scan within **DBDataManipulatorServiceContext** using: **lef.setPackagesToScan("com")** while **DBDataManipulatorService** is in **com.services**

Comment: That won't work , that scan is for the JPA entity classes, NOT for Spring beans, you have to add the @ComponentScan the way I have specified.

Comment: I may have missed one more thing - it looks like you require a `@Configuration` on your DBDataManipulatorServiceContext also, can you please try adding that too. If this does not work, can you please share a small part of your working test in a github project, that may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Autowired` annotation by default means that a bean must have been found otherwise you would have gotten a bean not found exception.

There are a few things that can cause this:

- The unit test is instantiated via `new DBDataManipulatorServiceContext()`instead of being scanned as a Spring Bean, in this case `@Autowired` is ignored.
- There is some XML configuration that overrides the annotations configuration, and so the bean is first created with autowiring on, and then later is discarded by a bean defined in XML with no parameter provided for the missing property

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but , you didn't show me how to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the DBDataManipulatorService class somehow. Use @service or @component annotation over class name. This will tell spring to manage the class and thus to inject it in your test.

Comment: What's in DBDataManipulatorServiceTestContext? I guess you replicate the content of DBDataManipulatorServiceContext class. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Should I change something?